PWM output with NUCLEO-F429ZI in uVision using just registers
I am using the NUCLEO-F429ZI board and I am trying to send a PWM output signal.
More specifically I am configuring the PE9 pin in TIM1_CH1
void BasicPWMMode1()
{

// GPIOE clock enable
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOEEN;

// Set PE9 alternate function
GPIOE->MODER &= ~(3 << 18);
GPIOE->MODER |= (2 << 18);

// Alternate function to TIM1 CH1
GPIOE->AFR[1] &= ~0xff;


// Enable TIM1 clock
RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 0);

// Set Prescaler and Auto Reload Register to slow the
//  processor down so we can see the LED blink.
// Freq = 12MHz / ((12000 - 1) * (1000 - 1)) = 1Hz
TIM1->PSC = 12000 - 1;
TIM1->ARR = 1000 - 1;

// Capture/Compare Register set the Duty Cycle
// Duty Cycle = ARR / CCR1 = 999 / 500 = .50 = 50%
TIM1->CCR1 = 500;

// PWM Mode 1
TIM1->CCMR1 |= (6 << 4) | (1 << 3);

// CC1E Enable output
TIM1->CCER |= 1;

// Master Output Enable
TIM1->BDTR |=(1 << 15);

// Enable/Start Timer
TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;

}

But I don't get an output at all(I get 0V output).
Do I have to call it in some way or is my code wrong?
SOLUTION:
I figured it out
    void BasicPWMMode1()
{

// GPIOE clock enable
RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOEEN;

// Set PE9 alternate function
GPIOE->MODER &= ~(3 << 18);
GPIOE->MODER |= (2 << 18);
// Alternate function to TIM1 CH1
GPIOE->AFR[1] &= ~(0xF << 4); // Clear alternate function bits for PE9
GPIOE->AFR[1] |= (1 << 4);    // Set AF1 for PE9

// Enable TIM1 clock
RCC->APB2ENR |= (1 << 0);

// Set Prescaler and Auto Reload Register to slow the
//  processor down so we can see the LED blink.
// Freq = 12MHz / ((12000 - 1) * (1000 - 1)) = 1Hz
TIM1->PSC = 12000 - 1;
TIM1->ARR = 1000 - 1;

// Capture/Compare Register set the Duty Cycle
// Duty Cycle = ARR / CCR1 = 999 / 500 = .50 = 50%
TIM1->CCR1 = 500;
    
    TIM1->CNT = 0; // Reset the current count.
    
// PWM Mode 1
TIM1->CCMR1 &= ~TIM_CCMR1_OC1M;         // Clear the OC1M bits
TIM1->CCMR1 |= (6 << TIM_CCMR1_OC1M_Pos); // Set PWM mode 1 (110)
TIM1->CCMR1 |= TIM_CCMR1_OC1PE;         // Enable preload register on TIM1_CCR1
// CC1E Enable output
TIM1->CCER |= 1;
// Master Output Enable
TIM1->BDTR |=(1 << 15);

// Enable/Start Timer

TIM1->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN;
    
TIM1->EGR |= TIM_EGR_UG;
     
}


// Alternate function to TIM1 CH1 
GPIOE->AFR[1] &= ~0xff;

I don't know what do you want to achieve with this.
In 'F429, TIM1_CH1 on PE9 is AF1, so you need to set GPIOE_AFR[1].AFRH9 = 1. Assuming reset state (GPIOE_AFR[1] = 0):
GPIOE->AFR[1] |= (0x01 << (4 * (9 - 8)));

